# Getting InvalidRequestError in stripe

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I get following error:

```
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\stripe\api_requestor.py", line 151, in handle_error_response
    raise err
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_jQhnYD0I72zs8l: No such customer: cus_Fi7AiNV2Cpdkdi
```

My code:

```
def payment_method_create_view(request):
    print("Ajax payment")
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if not billing_profile:
            return HttpResponse({"message": "Cannot find this user "}, status=401)
        token = request.POST.get("token")
        print("token is:", token)
        if token is not None:
            new_card_obj = Card.objects.add_new(billing_profile, token)
            print(new_card_obj)
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Your card was added."})
    return HttpResponse("error", status=401)


class CardManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(active=True)

    def add_new(self, billing_profile, token):
        if token:
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(billing_profile.customer_id)
            stripe_card_response = customer.sources.create(source=token)
            new_card = self.model(
                billing_profile = billing_profile,
                stripe_id       = stripe_card_response.id,
                brand           = stripe_card_response.brand,
                country         = stripe_card_response.country,
                exp_month       = stripe_card_response.exp_month,
                exp_year        = stripe_card_response.exp_year,
                last4           = stripe_card_response.last4
                )
            new_card.save()
            return new_card
        return None

class Card(models.Model):
    billing_profile      = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_id            = models.CharField(max_length=120) 
    brand                = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True) 
    country              = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True) 
    exp_month            = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    exp_year             = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    last4                = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    default              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects              = CardManager()
```

Comment: Sounds like cus_Fi7AiNV2Cpdkdi doesn't exist — can you find them in your Stripe dashboard? Maybe it's a customer that was deleted, or your database changed the ID, or something.

Answer (score 0):

## I deleted my billing profile from admin and change Cards to Card

def new_card_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.default:
        billing_profile = instance.billing_profile
        qs = Card.objects.filter(billing_profile=billing_profile).exclude(pk=instance.pk)
        qs.update(default=False)
post_save.connect(new_card_post_save_receiver, sender=Card)

Comment: Is this an answer or additional info for your question?